# Magento: How to add active cms-links to the Topmenu?

Tags: php, css, magento

I added this piece of code to the top.phtml. Its a hack from the magento-wiki to get an active Homepage-Link in the Topmenu. It works fine.

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <!-- HOME BUTTON HACK -->
        <?php $_anyActive = false; foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category) { $_anyActive = $_anyActive || $this->isCategoryActive($_category); } ?>
        <li class="first <?php echo !$_anyActive ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?></span></a></li>
        <!-- HOME BUTTON HACK-->
```

Problems occur when i try to add another link into Topmenu. So i add right behind the Home Button Hack

```
        <li class="<?php echo !$_anyActive ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('references')?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('References') ?></span></a></li>
```

Problem: Now the the homepage and the cms (reference) link are both simultaneous active or inactive.

How to get this piece of code going?

Greets

ImI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all magento pages are in "Default Category".
So When you have not entered any category magento see's you in "Default category".
That's why you cannot separate CMS page from home page (It's a cms page too btw) using is_active of category Object